# Can a rails controller request mutual SSL authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ssl

[`force_ssl`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods/force_ssl) can be used on a Rails controller to request SSL. But is there any way for a controller to request *mutual* authentication, and if yes, how it can the controller, request context, discover the certificate presented by client during the SSL/TLS handshake?

Comment: Considering that controllers execute long after the handshake, I guess the controller can only notice the fact that mutual auth did or did not occur, and the proper place to configure it is in the HTTP server (ie. Apache). Question still remains if the request contains the client cert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access you client certificate using the request.cgi

```
certificate = request.cgi.env_table['SSL_CLIENT_CERT'].gsub(/(\n|-----(BEGIN|END) CERTIFICATE-----)/, '');
```

Now you can find a user based on this certificate.

See http://www.scatmania.org/projects/ssl-client-certificate-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails/ for further information.

I am not sure if this works only if you are using a specific server(apache w. passenger e.g.).

Edit:

http://www.modssl.org/docs/2.8/ssl_reference.html#ToC24 might be useful too.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is kind of old question, but, it's top hit when you try to find out how mutual authentication could be done with Rails applications. And I spend a lot of time for find out good article and good way to do it. So, let me share in here what I find out. I hope it will help next guys who is trying to find out same answer.

Basically, It's kind of possible, but you need to do some trick. Because it's only possible to acquire a client certificate during the TLS handshake process.

I think most of a Rails web app designed to run behind proxy servers or load balancers. And this case TLS handshake process already done before web request come to your Rails controller.

So, there are several tricks you can use.

- Run separated endpoint with Ruby HTTP client and provide all required root certificate and private key. From rails controller, you need force to redirect to that Ruby HTTP client's endpoint, until your client (browser) successfully authenticates with client certificate.
- Configure NGINX that require Mutual TLS Authentication then pass actual raw client certificate from the HTTP request to your Rails controller. So, this way you need setup special url or special port for Nginx configuration and from Rails controller you need force to redirect that endpoint. And that special endpoint can proxy your actual Rails controller with HTTP parameters (X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_raw_cert). So, from there you can read actual client certificate and validate it with a Ruby OpenSSL library.

If you need more info, [please check this article.](https://medium.com/@zogoo/multi-tenant-rails-application-and-client-certificate-authentication-dd6d2bc40dd)